# How to run test Containers with spring boot and spock

Tags: spring, docker, spock, testcontainers

I want to use test container with spock on my spring boot application.

these are my dependencies :

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile 'org.testcontainers:spock:1.8.3'
    runtime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.15'
    compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok')

    compile 'org.testcontainers:testcontainers:1.8.3'
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile "org.spockframework:spock-core:1.1-groovy-2.4-rc-4"
    testCompile "org.spockframework:spock-spring:1.1-groovy-2.4-rc-4"
    testCompile 'com.github.testcontainers:testcontainers-spock:-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

I have initialized  my test like below :

```
@SpringBootTest
@Testcontainers
class ProductRedisRepositoryTest extends Specification {

    @Autowired
    ProductRedisRepository productRedisRepository

    @Autowired
    TestComponent testComponent


    static Consumer<CreateContainerCmd> cmd = { -> e.withPortBindings(new PortBinding(Ports.Binding.bindPort(6379), new ExposedPort(6379)))}

    @Shared
    public static GenericContainer redis =
            new GenericContainer("redis:3.0.2")
                    //.withExposedPorts(6379)
                    .withCreateContainerCmdModifier(cmd)

    def "check redis repository save and get"(){

        given:
            Product product = Product.builder()
                    .brand("brand")
                    .id("id")
                    .model("model")
                    .name( "name")
                    .build()
        when:
            productRedisRepository.save(product)
            Product persistProduct = productRedisRepository.find("id")

        then:
            persistProduct.getName() == product.getName()
    }

}
```

But it doesn't initiate redis container when I run test.
What is my mistake. How can I do that.

My springBootVersion = '2.0.4.RELEASE' and I am using Intelij.

This is the log output : [LOG](http://pasted.co/8d7ed79c)

Comment: can you provide log output?

Comment: Please consider changing `compile 'org.testcontainers:spock...'` to `testCompile 'org.testcontainers:spock...'`. You can also remove the obsolete `testCompile 'com.github.testcontainers:testcontainers-spock...'` line.

Comment: @gesellix I did what you say but the result still same. I have added log output at the end of the post.

Comment: another typo: please change `{ -> e.withPortBindings ...` to `{ e -> e.withPortBindings ...`. Or even simpler with `{ it.withPortBindings ...`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please remove the `static` keyword at your `@Shared` GenericContainer field.

Static fields won't be annotated with `@FieldMetadata` by the Spock Framework, hence they won't be considered as part of the spec's fields.
Testcontainers-Spock relies on those fields to recognise GenericContainers.

If you need the `static` modifier though, you can work around the issue like this:

```
...

public static GenericContainer staticRedis =
        new GenericContainer("redis:3.0.2")
                //.withExposedPorts(6379)
                .withCreateContainerCmdModifier(cmd)

@Shared
public GenericContainer redis = staticRedis

...
```